# How do I POST XML data to a webservice with Postman?

Tags: xml, web-services, post, postman

I want POST an XML request to a webservice using Postman. However, when I check the available request formats, I only see options for `form-data`, `x-www-form-urlencoded`, `raw`, and `binary`.

How do I POST an XML request to a webservice with Postman?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Send XML requests with the `raw` data type, then set the Content-Type to `text/xml`.

---

1. After creating a request, use the dropdown to change the request type to **POST**.

   [image: Set request type to POST]
2. Open the **Body** tab and check the data type for **raw**.

   [image: Setting data type to raw]
3. Open the Content-Type selection box that appears to the right and select either **XML (application/xml)** or **XML (text/xml)**

   [image: Selecting content-type text/xml]
4. Enter your raw XML data into the input field below

   [image: Example of XML request in Postman]
5. Click **Send** to submit your XML Request to the specified server.

   [image: Clicking the Send button]

Comment: alas, it's gone! It seems only available on chrome as extension.

Comment: @snr Postman is still available as [a desktop application](https://www.postman.com/).

Comment: @Stevoisiak can you please give me a suggestions how to read this xml file into PHP, I have no idea how to read body xml data in to the php.

Comment: @snr, in the Postman desktop app, you select Body>raw>XML, which, by default, gives you a Content-Type=application/xml header, then you deselect that default header and add a custom Content-Type=text/xml.  I can't imagine a more convoluted way of doing it.

Comment: be careful with newlines when adding the xml body in Postman desktop app. Because of the new lines my request was failling