# Postman: Send XML as body using application/x-www-form-urlencoded as content type

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, postman

Ok, first thing: I am not responsible for this code.
I am dealing with a router. This router has a web interface, and the code I'm about to show is in the router's web interface.
My job is to build an app to configure this router.
And I need my app to perform the login operation in the router.

The thing is: the developers that created the web interface for this router, made the router accept a post request in which the body of the request is xml, and the content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` !!!! (whaaaaaat???)

[image: request being sent]

The source code that generates this request is in the page:

```
function PostXML_log(pUrl, value) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'xml',
        url: pUrl,
        processData: false,
        data: value,
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function () { show_message("wait"); },
        success: function (data) {
            var code = $(data).find('CODE').text();
            if (code == "0" || code == "-1") {
                $.cookie.json = false;
                $.cookie("stork", $(data).find('MESSAGE').text(), { expires: 1 });
                if (code == "-1")
                    window.location = "mac_err.html";
                else
                    location.href = "../main_status.html";
            }
            else show_message("error", err_message)
        },
        error: function () { show_message("error", 'loading Error...'); },
        timeout: 20000
    });

}

function loginIn() {
    var username = 'admin';//$('#username').val();
    var password = ASCII2HEX($('#login_pwd').val());
    var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LOGIN><USER_NAME>' + username + '</USER_NAME><PASSWD>' + password + '</PASSWD></LOGIN>';
    PostXML_log("/cgi-bin/cgi.cgi?/app/route/login", xml);
};
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to replicate this behavior using Postman. I couldn't find a way to send a body and use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as content type at the same time.

I tried 4 different strategies with no success:

1 - Send as body, using content type application/xml, results in no response being received (send as pure text or text/xml results the same):

[image]

2 - Send xml as form key, results in error

[image]

3 - Send xml as form value, results in error

[image]

4 - send xml as both key and value, error: (i tried putting the xml's `<xml>` tag as key and the `<login>` tag as value, as well as putting the whole xml as key and value, no luck)

[image]

Comment: form-urlencoded data implies sending key/value pairs. You probably need to find out what key name is used for the xml string on receiving end

Comment: no key name is being used, as pointed by what is logged in the browser. I posted a print screen in the question showing this behavior

Comment: So are you saying the `$.ajax` does work? If it does you should be able to inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network and inspect headers, body etc

Comment: yes, the ajax does work. As I said, I posted a print screen of the request in the question

Comment: Perhaps the cookies are required? Also take a look at the "view URL encoded" request body, perhaps it has clues

Comment: No, this is the login form. No cookie is expected to be set. Also, the web interface works without any cookie previously set, and the request does not set any cookie as well

Comment: Also, the question is: How can I mimic this behavior using postman?

Comment: Perhaps needs same referrer? Can't see what is set as headers in postman images

Comment: As mentioned above all I can suggest is duplicating headers from working request

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking: how to replicate the request headers in postman?

Comment: To see the postman images, you need to click in the image, then apply zoom

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295675/how-do-i-post-xml-data-to-a-webservice-with-postman

Comment: @AmerAlmadany this is not what I'm asking

Comment: i know this is from forever ago @user3303864, but in your samples your data isn't actually encoded. if it were you'd have `%3C` instead of `<` (for example). my understanding of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is that the caller is responsible for encoding prior to putting it on the wire.