# Post XML return "405 Unsupported Media Type"

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm developing a Web API to upload XML files, but when I try to send a XML file to the route I receive the following error:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
    "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "status": 415,
    "traceId": "80000018-0000-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb"
}
```

I'm making a test from Postman, my controller has the following function:

```
namespace NFEApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UploadController : ControllerBase
    {
        // POST api/upload
        [HttpPost]
        public string Post([FromBody] XmlElement request)
        {
            return request.OuterXml;
        }
    }
}
```

Added in header **"Content-Type: application/xml"**, send a XML file as "binary", send a XML text as "raw" with type "XML (application/xml)" e nothing works. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `AddXmlSerializerFormatters()` in ConfigureServices as below that you could serialise objects to and from XML:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().AddXmlSerializerFormatters().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }
```

More details about how to upload xml file you could refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295675/how-do-i-post-xml-data-to-a-webservice-with-postman)

Answer (score -1):

If you post your XML as Raw text in the body, just have a string as a parameter in your API method.

```c#
namespace NFEApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UploadController : ControllerBase
    {
        // POST api/upload
        [HttpPost]
        public string Post([FromBody] string xml)
        {
            return xml;
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative is to have a **IFormCollection** as a parameter in your API method and send a form as **multipart/form-data**.